# Email quota for app scripts G suite users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps, google-forms, outgoing-mail

This is my simple app script I am using in google forms:

```
function onFormSubmit(event) 
{
  var x = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
}
```

I just signed up for a free trial for G suite.
On this link it is mentioned that G Suite users get 1500 emails per day.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

But when I run the above script in debug mode and check the value of x get it as 100(Which is the limit for normal account)

Is it that trial users have this limit? Or is it something else I have to do to associate the google forms with the G Suite account?
I have created the form with this G suite account from google drive.

Comment: Yes trial accounts have the 100 limit, see here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short answer

Yes, G Suite trial accounts have lower limits

## Explanation

From [Gmail sending limits in G Suite](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en)

> ### Increase your limits by ending your free trial
>
> Some limits are specific to trial accounts. At the end of your free trial period,
>   those limits will be automatically increased when your domain is
>   cumulatively billed for at least USD 30 (or the same amount in your
>   currency). If you purchased your domain from Google, the amount
>   required to increase your sending limits is USD 30 plus the cost of
>   your domain.
>
> If you want to increase your limits sooner, you can end your free
>   trial and pay the amount now. For instructions, see [Make a manual
>   payment](https://support.google.com/a/a/answer/6140582?hl=en). It can take up to 48 hours to upgrade the limits after you
>   submit the payment.
>
> **Important**: While you're still in your trial period, your sending
>   limits will not be increased.