# G-Suite limited to 100 emails per day

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-workspace, quota

I am working with G-suite to send emails through script from sheets (linked from google forms).

As I was limited to 100 per day in a personal account, I have upgraded this to a G-suite but the daily email quota through the gmail@company name is still 100?

My academy uses g suite and I tested with their mail system, the quota shows to be 1500. So then, what is the issue?

I am using the g-suite for a different project. Is this limited to the trail period? Is this issue lifted when the trail period is over?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Email quota for app scripts G suite users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41520186/email-quota-for-app-scripts-g-suite-users)

Comment: To add to what @Kos said, please see this note: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#note1.

Comment: Ah right,It needs several billing cycles to approve of the 1500 limit. Thanks then, but how many number of billing cycles then if less than 10 users for complete activation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone, after several chats with the google support team
I have realized a few things

1. The G-suite accounts needs 30 days minimum for it start working like
   a G-suite to remove spam accounts
2. Even if you pay early(for 6 cycles) to access G-suite features, it needs to complete the trial period of 14 days,then your limit is extended to 1500.
3. I am still confused about   the quota (different members said different things) I wouldn't know the result until 30 days(when limit goes up to 500 or 1500) or just trial period is lifted for billing cycle. I think the end of trail period is to indicate the start of billing cycle, meaning the G-Suite is restricted to consumer email until 30 days and after 30 days the limit starts increasing to 500, and then after a few more cycles, the limit goes up to 1500.
4. Sending Emails via Apps Script is
   much different from sending Emails via Browser as it goes to the
   Google SMTP server. Apps Script is different.(But I tested the same
   thing in an academic mail, same script, the limit showed 1500)
   **SMTP relay limits are lower for trial accounts. To increase SMTP relay limits for a trial account, you must pay a Google-generated bill.  This is different than increasing Gmail limits, which can be initiated by ending your free trial.**
5. The google apps script is third party system and app script is out of their scope

---

> So in effect, you need to complete at-least one monthly
>   bill from google to get the 1500 limit until then
>   your G-Suite account will act as a consumer (@gmail.com)

---

Comment: Please, mark your answer as correct. See:

https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/

Answer (score 0):

As @IMTheNachoMan said in the documentation for [Current Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas) you have a Note that states:

> Note: Newly created G Suite domains are subject to the consumer limit for the first billing cycle if they have six or more users, or several billing cycles if they have fewer users. For more information, see the Help Center page on [sending limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852).

So if you have more than five users you are limited for the first billing cycle, if you have less I recommend you to contact [G-Suite Support](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)